# Potential of using microtime as a unique identifier

Tags: javascript, php

If a user submits a microtime value of which is then tracked by the server session. Would it be possible to track the microtime, alike that of an RSA style passphrase for encrypting the data sent and received from the server.

And would that be a reliable method for an auto/dynamic passphrase generation.

Not sure if this is the correct stack for this.

Comment: Why is microtime (which is somewhat predictable -- you know the rough range) better than a random number? And why generate this on the client and not on the server?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to use the microtime value for.  Are you just trying to create a unique identifier for a given client?  Or, are you trying to create some secure, unpredictable key which can be used for secure operations?

Comment: another way to ask the same question is: how close to one another are computers times. if micro time is milliseconds then are two different clients likely to ever be the exact same time.

Comment: _Hashing_ is a one-way operation — if the client _hashes_ the data and sends it to the server, there is _no way_ for the server to recover the original data in order to act upon it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are several problems here, so I'll try to address them before the actual question:

> using microtime as a unique identifier

Would only work if you never generate two identifiers in the same microsecond *and* your time function really measured microseconds *and* time was monotonic (always increasing). All three are shaky assumptions.

It is very possible to generate two identifiers in the same microsecond. Your time function may not have the precision you think it is, or the precision the data type implies (e.g. it might always return values ending in 000). Finally, stuff like daylight savings time and [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) may turn time *backwards*, and you end up reusing ids.

So no, microtime as unique identifier is not a good idea in production.

> RSA style passphrase

RSA is an asymmetric key crypto system. It allows parties to have public and private keys, derived from truly random numbers, and send data encrypted and/or signed to each other with reasonable security. An RSA public key looks like this (modulus in hexadecimal):

```
af 46 03 ce c7 13 e6 2e 93 d8 56 91 b1 31 8d 0a 
22 c1 f0 eb 4f 5e ef 0d f6 20 32 b9 a4 4e 87 f9 
d2 d2 44 51 b0 df 30 50 c9 35 4e 68 19 84 fb 98 
33 aa 05 4b 7e fb 57 c5 b6 2e a8 4b 04 ca cf 5e 
2e e5 9e 1b ca b7 60 c5 58 2c b0 df c4 6b 0d b1 
2c 33 97 73 54 61 2b 9a 1b b1 dc 5d 10 a9 c4 c8 
f7 6c e3 55 6e b5 0e 61 3b 35 24 0b 89 1e 32 a2 
75 69 4e 97 40 68 ee 23 48 f2 71 9f c7 7e e2 9d 
6c 22 55 36 24 64 a4 f0 b6 52 58 5a 9a 44 e7 3b 
2a d5 ed 95 63 f8 1d a8 4d 45 9b 5d c2 f2 f9 74 
81 06 18 d5 b1 fb b0 7e 5d 50 1f 63 5c a0 73 f5 
22 b2 57 64 03 e6 b7 0f 6f b7 58 0b 57 80 56 51 
65 9f f5 09 61 63 29 62 4d 30 02 3a 64 10 2d 95 
b8 12 36 04 58 c5 d7 1d 95 e2 21 3c b0 b3 93 35 
b2 b1 f9 6d 7e 20 66 b2 68 33 e9 50 a8 15 1e 0a 
80 9a 3c 19 dd cc 79 35 a8 8c 1b 61 33 5d 12 2f
```

A passphrase is a long-ish string of letters and symbols (usually) chosen by a user, and used to provide authentication or generate repeatable random numbers (e.g. brain wallet for bitcoin). A passphrase looks like this:

```
correct horse battery staple
```

"RSA *style* passphrase" is a very weird expression and I don't know what you mean, but signals you may be under some misunderstanding.

> for hashing the data sent and received from the server

Why are you hashing the data sent and received from the server? *Hashing* means taking some bytes and mangling them beyond recognition to a short size, in a repeatable way that is hard to guess. A secure channel, like TLS, may use hashing inside, but it should be completely invisible to the programmer using it.

Maybe instead of *hashing* you mean *encrypting*. Encrypting is taking some data and a key, and mangling them in a way that only someone holding the key can undo the process. A hash, on the other hand, has no key and (hopefully) no way to undo. This might seem like nitpicking, but cryptography is *hard* and *subtle*, requiring extreme attention.

---

Complaints aside, answering your question.

If I understood correctly, you want to use the system clock, with microsecond precision, to generate some sort of key material (key, passphrase, nonce or equivalent) to secure client-server communications (hashing to ensure integrity, encrypting, or something similar).

This might make sense because an attacker will never know the exact microsecond you generated the key. And the data type is fairly large, probably 128-bits, the size of a good key.

But the time *is not random*. The attacker doesn't know the exact microsecond, but they can *guess*. If they know the hour, they have only `60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000 = 3600000000`, less than 4 billion possibilities. And for cryptography we consider attackers that can make that many guesses *in less than a second*. 4 billion is just 32 bits of security, a negligible amount for securing data.

Proposed solutions, according to modern best practices:

- **if you just need unique identifier, no cryptography involved**: use a [UUID version 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29), which has implementations in practically every language. They have a collision chance of one in 5316911983139663491615228241121378304, which should be enough. They are guessable, though.
- **if you need a unique/random value for cryptography purposes** (and you are a cryptographer who knows what you are doing): use `/dev/urandom` on Linux, available as a CryptoRandom library in most languages.
- **if you want a secure channel between client and server**: use TLS. You can get a free certificate from [StartSSL](https://www.startssl.com/) or [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) shortly. I suggest using a proxy like nginx to deal with the TLS/SSL stuff and then you can use plain HTTP in your main application.
- **if you want to securely exchange data in some other way**: use the [NaCl library](http://nacl.cr.yp.to/), which has been ported to many languages. It has functions to encrypt and sign data with secure defaults and state-of-art crypto.

---

This is not meant to bash you. It's just that cryptography is hard and you get only one chance. So please be careful. If you are a cryptographer or want to learn more, I suggest asking the [Security community](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Your assumptions were correct. Absolutely makes sense now many thanks.